# Wordpress plugin installed twice

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing **WP plugin** for my website. When I upload plugin to WP **I see 2 instances installed**.

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: Maybe the plugins have different folder names in `wp-content/plugins`.

Comment: There were no plugins and I've just installed only 1

Comment: Maybe you are calling/adding it twice in your code. What does your initial file looks like?

Comment: I had the same issue! Turns out the text "Plugin Name:" was also in the comments of the uninstall.php file. Remove the useless comments and voila

Answer (score 3):

Check your plugin directory.

Path: `wp-content-->plugins`

There is a may be two same plugin directory or same name.
Check and change plugin name is same or not? (In your plugin development main files.)

```
/* 
Plugin Name: Your plugin name
*/
```

If plugin name is same the change name different and save it.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issue and it was additional php files in the individual plugins folders.  I had copied a .php file to -old.php and -original.php - When I deleted the extra copied php files, the extra plugin entries disappeared!

Comment: I too made the same mistake, copied a `.php` file just to back it up, and ended up with two plugins listed by WP.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me recently. I saw the same plugin listed twice in the installed plugins section.

Upon investigating, I noiticed that a while back I had made a duplicate copy of the main plugin file. So the file was "copy of plugin_name.php" in the same directory as the main plugin_name.php. I deleted the copy file and the duplicate entry was gone.

Answer (score 2):

You have to Enter declarations just in the main plugin php file.

Make sure you did not enter plugin declarations into another included php file in the plugin directory.

Make sure this code is not in another php file:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: My Plugin Name
* Plugin URI: http://mypluginuri.com/
* Description: A brief description about your plugin.
* Version: 1.0 or whatever version of the plugin (pretty self explanatory)
* Author: Plugin Author's Name
* Author URI: Author's website
* License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL12
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing worth noting is that **a wordpress plugin name have nothing to do with it's directory name**. Instead, it's name depends upon the comment section of the `.php` files that are within the directory. These files themselves may start with any name but are usually registered with index.php.

A typical plugin declaration looks like this.

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: My Plugin Name
* Plugin URI: http://mypluginuri.com/
* Description: A brief description about your plugin.
* Version: 1.0 or whatever version of the plugin (pretty self explanatory)
* Author: Plugin Author's Name
* Author URI: Author's website
* License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL12
*/
```

So just look for two different files that consists of a comment like this. These files may be residing anywhere, even in directory of another plugins. The `Plugin Name` parameter will consist of your actual plugin name.

Answer (score 1):

**Why this happen?**

As we know,Plugin is peace of code block.Plugin is identified from the section that we write in main plugin file.

```
/**
 * @package Akismet
 */
/*
Plugin Name: Akismet
Plugin URI: https://akismet.com/
Description: Used by millions, Akismet is quite possibly the best way in the world to <strong>protect your blog from spam</strong>. 
Version: 3.2
Author: Automattic
Author URI: https://automattic.com/wordpress-plugins/
License: GPLv2 or later
Text Domain: akismet
*/
```

When You copy this and put in some other plugin folder main plugin file.You are see to `Akismet` at admin panel.

**How to Get Ride from this?**

**Step-1**:Check plugin have information in you plugin dir.

**Step-2**:Change Version so you can identify which one is original which is duplicate.

**Step-3**:Simply change information.

That's it.